# openfire cannot open 'Admin Web Console'

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, openfire

I  get the openfire source code , compile and run ,everything is well.   but cannot open  'Admin Web Console'

the web error code:

http error 500 
 Problem accessing/index.jsp. Reason: jsp support not configured.

the eclipse logcat:

12:02:00,444  INFO /:2052 - No JSP support.  Check that JSP jars are in lib/jsp and that the JSP option has been specified to start.jar

Comment: Are the JSP jars in `lib/jsp`? Has the JSP option been specified to `start.jar`?

Comment: I only get jsp-api-2.1.jar, servlet-api-2.5-6.1.9.jar  in lib/  ,   maybe miss other jars, but where to get?    and how to specified  to start.jar?   thank you!!